# How to cancel particular recurring local notification and reschedule it for next week in iOS 10(Swift)

Tags: swift3, ios10, unusernotificationcenter

I have created different local notifications to set for weekdays and weekends to repeat continuously

```
let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerWeekly, repeats: true)
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.body = "TIME_TO_STEP_SHAPA".localized
content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "\(notificationType)-\(reminderType)-\(day)", content: content, trigger: trigger)

UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { (settings) in
    if settings.authorizationStatus != .authorized {
        print("Local notifications are not authorized by the user")
    }
}
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) {(error) in
    if error != nil {
        print("Error: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

and cancelling particular notification verifying with notifications based on proper conditions and updating the same notification for next week.

```
if (type == notificationType && notificationWeekDay == currentWeekDay) {
    //Cancelling local notification
    app.cancelLocalNotification(notif)

    let fireDate = self.getUpdatedNotification(currentDate: currentLocalDate!, fireDate: notificationFireDate!)

    HikeCommonUtils.setUpLocalNotification(fireDate, type: notificationType, reminderType: reminderType)
}
```

and updating the next fire date using

```
func getUpdatedNotification(currentDate: Date, fireDate : Date) ->Date {
    let calendar = Calendar.autoupdatingCurrent
    let dateComponents = (calendar as NSCalendar).components(([.year, .month, .day]), from: currentDate)
    let timeComponents = (calendar as NSCalendar).components(([.hour, .minute, .second]), from: fireDate)
    var dateComps = DateComponents()
    dateComps.day = dateComponents.day! + 7
    dateComps.month = dateComponents.month
    dateComps.year = dateComponents.year
    dateComps.hour = timeComponents.hour
    dateComps.minute = timeComponents.minute
    dateComps.second = timeComponents.second
    let itemDate = calendar.date(from: dateComps)
    return itemDate!
}
```

Even after removing notification firing for the removed date because of repeat 'true'.

Is there any option for adding start date in local notifications in iOS 10?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating notification trigger details with

```
var triggerWeekly = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .second], from: fireDate)
        triggerWeekly.weekday = day
```

Instead of

```
            let triggerWeekly = calendar.dateComponents([.weekday, .hour, .minute, .second], from: fireDate)
```

Worked for firedate update

Answer (score 0):

You can add logic to `nextTriggerDate()`

```
func nextTriggerDate()
```

The next date at which the trigger conditions will be met.

**Discussion**

Use this property to find out when a notification associated with this trigger will next be delivered.